# I received an error when I did a kubectl exec -it - I cant get into the shell of the pod I would like to access

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, devops

I am still new in Kubernetes, and I wanted to get into the shell of a pod within my K8s cluster. I am getting this following error:

xhcalderone@k8s-master:/data$ kubectl exec -it nginx-test -- /bin/bash
Error from server: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.0.1.131:10250: i/o timeout
xhcalderone@k8s-master:/data$

I am not sure why I am receiving it.

Comment: Hi, are you using virtualbox or azure virtual machine?

Comment: Hi! I am using AWS EC2.

Comment: Can you check which docker package you have installed on your ubuntu?